# How to repair/synchronize videos in DCIM folder with Photos app

Tags: iphone, video, photos.app

- I removed a file `large.MOV` from the DCIM/102APPLE folder. This video still appears in the camera roll, but understandably cannot be played.
- I also copied `restore.MOV` to the DCIM/102APPLE folder (that I had previously deleted) via iFunBox. It doesn't show up in the Photos app.

I think there is a similar problem with image files that are added/deleted outside of Apple software.

How can I remove `large.MOV` and add `restore.MOV` to the Photos app? My guess is an internal database used by the Photos app must be rebuilt.

I have tried forcing the Photos app to close, and rebooting my iPhone without success.

I'm guessing [How to Fix Your iPhoto Library When Some Photos Aren't Showing](http://www.scanyourentirelife.com/resources/iphoto/photos-disappeared-missing/photos-in-library-not-showing-in-iphoto/) might be a solution, but I don't have a Mac.

Comment: The folder structure of an iDevice is not a 'user-accessible/modifiable' area. You should **never** play in it as though it were an external hard drive. Any errors resulting from messing in there are unpredictable at best, terminal at worst.

Comment: Also, your 'link' is not actually a link :/